# Bible (Judges 16) silence or lack of info on Delilah's physical beauty says that deceptive pretentiousness & greed are Not based on good looks

Tags: textual-criticism, historical-interpretation, intertextuality, layers-of-meaning

Judges 16:4-22 NASB95

> 4 After this it came about that he loved a woman in the valley of
> Sorek, whose name was Delilah. 5 The lords of the Philistines came up
> to her and said to her, “Entice him, and see where his great strength
> lies and how we may overpower him that we may bind him to afflict
> him. Then we will each give you eleven hundred pieces of silver.” 6 So
> Delilah said to Samson, “Please tell me where your great strength is
> and how you may be bound to afflict you.” 7 Samson said to her, “If
> they bind me with seven fresh cords that have not been dried, then I
> will become weak and be like any other man.” 8 Then the lords of the
> Philistines brought up to her seven fresh cords that had not been
> dried, and she bound him with them. 9 Now she had men lying in wait in
> an inner room. And she said to him, “The Philistines are upon you,
> Samson!” But he snapped the cords as a string of tow snaps when it
> touches fire. So his strength was not discovered.
>
> 10 Then Delilah said to Samson, “Behold, you have deceived me and told
> me lies; now please tell me how you may be bound.” 11 He said to
> her, “If they bind me tightly with new ropes which have not been
> used, then I will become weak and be like any other man.” 12 So
> Delilah took new ropes and bound him with them and said to him, “The
> Philistines are upon you, Samson!” For the men were lying in wait in
> the inner room. But he snapped the ropes from his arms like a
> thread.
>
> 13 Then Delilah said to Samson, “Up to now you have deceived me and
> told me lies; tell me how you may be bound.” And he said to her,
> “If you weave the seven locks of my hair with the web [and
> fasten it with a pin, then I will become weak and be like any other
> man.” 14 So while he slept, Delilah took the seven locks of his
> hair and wove them into the web]. And she fastened it with the pin
> and said to him, “The Philistines are upon you, Samson!” But he awoke
> from his sleep and pulled out the pin of the loom and the web. Delilah
> Extracts His Secret
>
> 15 Then she said to him, “How can you say, ‘I love you,’ when your
> heart is not with me? You have deceived me these three times and have
> not told me where your great strength is.” 16 It came about when she
> pressed him daily with her words and urged him, that his soul was
> annoyed to death. 17 So he told her all that was in his heart and
> said to her, “A razor has never come on my head, for I have been a
> Nazirite to God from my mother’s womb. If I am shaved, then my
> strength will leave me and I will become weak and be like any other
> man.”
>
> 18 When Delilah saw that he had told her all that was in his heart,
> she sent and called the lords of the Philistines, saying, “Come up
> once more, for he has told me all that is in his heart.” Then the
> lords of the Philistines came up to her and brought the money in their
> hands. 19 She made him sleep on her knees, and called for a man and
> had him shave off the seven locks of his hair. Then she began to
> afflict him, and his strength left him. 20 She said, “The Philistines
> are upon you, Samson!” And he awoke from his sleep and said, “I will
> go out as at other times and shake myself free.” But he did not know
> that the Lord had departed from him. 21 Then the Philistines seized
> him and gouged out his eyes; and they brought him down to Gaza and
> bound him with bronze chains, and he was a grinder in the prison. 22
> However, the hair of his head began to grow again after it was shaved
> off.

Delilah is a really terrible person because she wants to trick Samson in order to gain the secrets behind his strength.  The Philistines told Delilah that in exchange for revealing Samson's secrets, they would give her materialistic wealth.

She is deceptively pretentious because she misleadingly tries to kindly & nicely convince Samson to reveal the secrets behind his strength.

We notice the fake kindness & niceness because she starts off in Judges 16:6 by saying "please" in a polite manner when she requests to find the secret of his strength. She tries to sweet-talk him.

The Judges 16:19 bible verse is extremely shocking because Delilah makes a U-turn in how she portrays herself.  To elaborate, in Judges 16:19, she fakes kindness & sweetness by enticing Samson to sleep on her knees so that another man can shave Samson's head.  Judges 16:19 later mentions that Delilah began to "afflict" Samson after his head was shaved off which she might have done in order to see if Samson's strength left him.  When she afflicts Samson, it shows bible readers like me that she starts showing her true colors of wickedness.

Delilah is greedy, and moreover, Delilah is a total fake.

It's important to note what the Bible suggests/hints by what it does not mention.

In this case, there is no mention of how physically attractive and/or no mention of how beautiful Delilah was.

The Bible does not say if Delilah was physically pretty or ugly.

Could we infer that the Bible suggests in Judges 16 that regardless of whether a person is physically pretty or ugly, they can still be deceptively pretentious and materialistically greedy?

Comment: I do not think we need divine wisdom to answer this question.  Almost any girl, regardless of physical beauty, can be sexually provocative and alluring.  This is scarcely a Bible question!

Comment: @dottard someone got out of bed on the wrong side today. Your snippy tone in your response is uncalled for.

Comment: I was making no attempt to be "snippy".  I was stating a rather obvious fact about which the Bible says very little.

Answer (score 1):

Judges 14:3,4

> 3.Then his father ( Samson's father) and his mother said unto him, Is there never a woman among the daughters of thy brethren, or among all
> my people, that thou goest to take a wife of the uncircumcised
> Philistines? And Samson said unto his father, Get her for me; for she
> pleaseth me well.
>
> 4.But his father and his mother knew not that it was of the Lord, that he sought an occasion against the Philistines: for at that time the
> Philistines had dominion over Israel.

Conclusion: An alternate translation for " she pleaseth me well " in verse 3 is " she is right in mine eyes " so therefore we have strong biblical support that Samson was attracted to physical beauty. Verse 4 leads us to realize God's ways are higher than our ways. If killing is approved by God under wartime conditions, I will not question some of what Samson did. Others may infer their on conclusions.

Comment: Your formatting cut off the quote. I corrected this. Please open the editing box to see how this was done.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP points out, the Bible says nothing about Delilah's beauty. The previous chapters of Samson's life show that he was attracted to Philistine women generally. Delilah was clearly motivated at least in part by greed. But she also may have been attracted to Samson physically. After all he was apparently the strongest man around. Meanwhile there is no hint that Delilah was ugly. Given Samson's history and his strong attraction to her, it is more reasonable to infer that she was beautiful.

I actually think the OP is too hard on Delilah. In addition to her bad qualities she was also motivated by patriotism - but she happened to be on the wrong side providentially. If one considers that Samson had personally killed at least 1000 of her countrymen (15:16), it is easy to understand that her wickedness in Israelite eyes was love of one's country to the Philistines. One need only to think of the story of Jael in Judges 4-5, or of Judith in the book named for her, to realize that our moral judgment of a woman's act of treacherous deceit depends on which political side we take. Like Mata Hari (a villain worthy of a firing squad to the French but a heroic agent and scapegoat for the Germans), her moral worth lay in the eyes of the beholder.

Comment: Sorry, Judges 16:5-6 strongly suggests that Delilah was strongly motivated by money.  In Judges 16:5, the Philistines offer Delilah financial reward if she finds the secrets behind Samson's strength, and almost Immediately in Judges 16:6, Delilah tries to sweet talk Samson into revealing the secrets behind his strength.  which strongly suggests Delilah is greedy.  Sorry, but your theory on Delilah's patriotic fervor as a Phlistine sounds far-fetched because there is No mention of any patriotic fervor coming from Delilah.

Comment: (Judges 16:5-6) The lords of the Philistines came up to her and said to her, “Entice him, and see where his great strength lies and how we may overpower him that we may bind him to afflict him. Then we will each give you eleven hundred pieces of silver.” 6 So Delilah said to Samson, “Please tell me where your great strength is and how you may be bound to afflict you.”